# How do I save a checkbox value on check using ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, save

I currently have a form where the user must check off checkboxes in a checkbox list before clicking a save button which saves their selections to the database. The list of values is retrieved from the database and bound to the checkbox list. So it's basically a dynamic list of checkboxes.

I'd like to change this so that a user's selection is immediately and automatically saved to the database once the user checks off a checkbox.

I thought this could just be done using an updatepanel, datalist, and checkboxes.

Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlServices" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:DataList ID="dlistAnimals" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAnimal" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="animal_click" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblAnimal" AssociatedControlID="chkAnimal" runat="server"<%#Eval("Name")%></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

"animal_click" is a function in the code-behind that will add or delete the value from the database using a stored procedure. If the selection was previous selected, it is removed but if the selection does not exist in the database, it is simply added.

This all works on my local machine but when I put it on a remote server, the form seems slow. The user will quickly check off multiple checkboxes but not all the selections were saved to the database. It gives the impression that the server isn't able to keep up with the user's actions quickly enough.

I'm not exactly sure why this is the case. If there's a better more efficient way of doing this, I'd be interested in suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried other controls like Repeater? Or try this approach: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/09/15/slow-performance-of-a-gridview-inside-an-updatepanel.aspx

Comment: I did look at repeaters before deciding to use a datagrid. The reason behind the datagrid was just because it was easier to implement.

Comment: In your sample you've used a DataList instead of a DataGrid. I asked you to try another control because a DataList does not use ViewState to maintain values across postbacks. This could possibly cause side-effects when used within AsyncPostbacks.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm going to take another look at the repeater. Also, my mistake with the datagrid, I meant to say datalist.

Comment: That was only a guess. But apart from that, have you tried to remove the `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to update always? Are you calling `upnlServices.Update` explicitely from codebehind? Just another guess.

Comment: I was just about to comment that the problem still remains. Tinkered around with the UpdatePanel some more and no difference. There seems to be some delay between what the user does and what shows up in the database. Sometimes all the values are recorded if left alone for a while and at other times, only some of the selections are actually saved.

Answer (score 0):

What about threading this? So the animal_click event will create a separate thread. So this won't cause the UI to wait on the update/insert to complete.

Something like this to call it:

```
MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(Threaded);
mi.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

and

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker();

private void Threaded()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I haven't thought about using threading before for something like this. I'm actually not sure what is causing the lag. My current thinking is that the updatepanel might be a big reason why things aren't working properly.

Comment: Try adding ChildrenAsTrigger="False" on your updatepanel if updatepanel is your suspect as the culprit of slowness. :D